# How do I return the correct name based on last in first out using a pandas df?

Tags: python, python-3.x, pandas

I'm struggling to get this working...
I'm trying to build a function last_in_first_out() that reads a csv into a df and returns the next name in line to go out.
The df is structured like this:

```
Time,Event,Executed
2023-06-30 06:48:16,IN,Eric
2023-06-30 07:19:13,OUT,Eric
2023-06-30 07:24:15,IN,Stan
2023-06-30 09:02:26,OUT,Stan
2023-06-30 09:03:33,IN,Wendy
2023-06-30 12:03:25,OUT,Wendy
2023-06-30 12:04:24,IN,Kenny
2023-06-30 13:41:24,IN,Kyle
2023-06-30 13:52:20,IN,Butters
2023-06-30 14:38:17,OUT,Butters
```

It works fine when the last entry was a `IN` but I'm struggling with the logic when I have multiple `IN` entries queued up. The next one in line to go `OUT` would be `Kyle` and after him `Kenny`. How would I solve this and have the right name returned based on 'LIFO'?

Answer (score 0):

For your data, the "Time"-column will sort the same way as a string and as a date, but in case the dates have a different format, you would want to set the "Time"-column as datetime first:

```
df['Time'] = pd.to_datetime(df['Time'])
```

You can filter the "Event"-column to only return "IN" values, then sort the values by "Time", get the last row, and return the value in the "Executed"-column like this:

```
df.loc[df["Event"] == "IN"].sort_values(by='Time').iloc[-1]['Executed']
```